# Pyqt Failed to resolve service name: proxy_resolver

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

Error:
[image]

My code:

```
self.textBrowser = QWebEngineView(self.frame)
self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 571, 192))
self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
self.textBrowser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl('http://127.0.0.1:5000/word'))
```

This textBrowser is worked and i can see the html.But There is always a lot of error message output.
  Who can give me some help!Thank you.If you can show the qt code with C++,That'll be ok.

Comment: you could show the code as text, besides providing a [mcve] and pointing out how you implement the server to try to reproduce your problem

Comment: What version of PyQt5 do you have? try using the latest version since it looks like it was a bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69281?focusedCommentId=411081&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel

Comment: My qt version is 5.11.2 and PyQt version is 5.11.3.

Comment: okay, does the same thing happen to urls like google: https://www.google.com/? If so, then it is probably a bug, so I recommend reporting it.

Comment: I'm not found some answer at google.My server is running by Flask at localhost.Everything look like okay but those message still output.

Comment: I think you have not understood me, I have not asked you to look for google solutions but use the google url: `self.textBrowser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl('https://www.google.com/'))`

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about it.I am not oftem use English.I try you Suggestion and it does't work.

Comment: it seems that you do not understand me, I have not pointed out that it is the solution, I just want to find out the cause of the error, for example you point out that setHtml works correctly, also point out that with a local url it generates that error message and now I ask you if it same happens to you with the url of google do you generate the same error with the url of google? On the other hand the latest version of PyQt5 is 5.11.3 so I recommend you update your PyQt

Comment: 'setUrl' will output it but setHtml is ok.Maybe i need to update it.But can you find what's wrong with this code.I run it on windows7,python3.6.

Comment: The piece of code you show is correct (I could not say the same about your other code since I do not see it). A bug is an internal problem that the developers of the libraries have (Qt or PyQt Developers), before that workaround can be given to *solve* the problem for old versions, but in another as I suspect in this the solution is to update the library. In conclusion your code is right for me, the problem is from the library

Answer (score 1):

1. pip install pyqt5==5.14.2
2. pip install PyQtWebEngine

ok 哈哈